# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, fonts, pagespeed

I'm working on improving [my website's](https://imthemoisturizer.com) performance on Google PageSpeed Insights and one of the errors I get is the one on the title: "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy".

[image: Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy (fonts)]

The greater part of this issue is caused by .woff2 fonts that are loaded from my server, so I've been searching for solutions and tried to modify my .htaccess file so that they are cached, but the problem persists.

This is what my .htaccess looks like now:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
(...)
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff2
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/bmp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/vnd.microsoft.icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A2419200
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A2419200
ExpiresByType application/zip A2419200
</IfModule>
```

I've seen plenty of cases in which "A2419200" is switched to the "access plus 1 year" kind of syntax, could that be the origin of the error?

Also, another potential solution I saw was including this piece of code, although I'm not sure if it'd be the right one:

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=84600, public"
</filesMatch>
```

After checking the Response headers on the Inspection tool I've noticed that cache info isn't stated, so there must be something I'm not doing right.

Thanks a lot in advance for your insights!